# Hierachy of buttons whiten UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am building a backend for an online app. It consists of a big `UITableView` with cells, each showing the title of a book, its author and two buttons, a "confirm delivery" button and a "problem" button. When the user clicks the confirm delivery, it displays a `UIAlertView` to confirm/cancel. If confirmed, it makes a POST `HTTP` Request (telling the web app that the book was succesfuly found and given to the user) and it removes its containing cell from the `TableView`. If they hit the problem button, the same thing happens, but telling the web app some error ('No stock', 'user leave without receiving the book', 'others').

My problem is assigning the responsibilities correctly. I created a "Cell" subclass of `UITableViewCell` containing an `order_id` property, outlets to both author and title labels, and two `IBActions` (from the confirm and error buttons). Is it correct to make the cell be responsible for containing the data of each order, performing the `HTTPRequest` and then deleting itself from the `UITableView`? This doesn't sound right to me, as I am putting the model content into a view.

Then I thought about using a protocol, but that's when I got all confused about the responsibilities, who should conform to the protocol, etc.

So, what do you guys think? Should I just have the `UITableViewCell` do the model work, breaking `MVC` just to keep things simple? Who should conform to the protocol that will be triggered when the confirm/cancel button gets clicked?

Comment: where are you confuse in this task, adding button or getting about , which button is press?

Comment: How should I address the problem. Should I use a delegate, called by the IBAction inside the Cell, or should I do things directly there?